Did the heavenly Temple have a separation of the two inner rooms?
After bringing the people out of Egypt, Moses received instructions to build a Tabernacle.
Exodus 25 (ESV)

8 And let them make me a sanctuary, that I may dwell in their midst. 9 Exactly as I show you concerning the pattern of the tabernacle, and of all its furniture, so you shall make it.

We know those instructions called for a curtain separating the Holy Place from the Holy of Holies. When the permanent Temple in Jerusalem was built it too followed instructions and continued to separate these two inner spaces.
In the New Testament we are told the earthly was a shadow of the heavenly, which Christ entered.
Hebrews 8:5

They serve a copy and shadow of the heavenly things. For when Moses was about to erect the tent, he was instructed by God, saying, “See that you make everything according to the pattern that was shown you on the mountain.”

Hebrews 9:24

For Christ has entered, not into holy places made with hands, which are copies of the true things, but into heaven itself, now to appear in the presence of God on our behalf.

Did the heavenly Temple have a separation of the two inner rooms? If so, was it temporary like the one on earth or was there never a separation in the heavenly which the earthly pattern temporarily hid until the curtain was torn?

In ch6 v19, we are told that Christ has entered into "the inner shrine behind the curtain".
Ch7 v9 reminds us that only the high priest can enter into the inner shrine.
In ch9 v12 we are told that Christ imitated the high priest (or rather provided the model for the high priest) by entering this inner sanctuary "with his own blood", i.e. as an effect of his death.
In ch9 vv8-9, we are told that "the outer tent is still standing (which is symbolic for the present age)" (RSV).
Putting those details together, my reading of the image is that the heavenly sanctuary is the equivalent of the inner room alone, and the outer of the two rooms is represented by the place where we are now.

Let us be very clear: Whatever the heavenly sanctuary is, it must be nothing like the earthly sanctuary for the following reasons:

the heavenly sanctuary is much larger than the earthly sanctuary
the heavenly sanctuary is not made of beaver skins, etc
the heavenly sanctuary does not have an outer court for the slaying of lambs etc, but the true Lamb of God, John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7
the heavenly sanctuary does not have an altar of burnt offering which represented the cross of Christ
the heavenly sanctuary does not have a laver but the reiver of the water of life that springs up to everlasting life, John 4:14
the heavenly sanctuary does not have a table of shew-bread but the true bread of life, Jesus, John 6:35, 48
the heavenly sanctuary does not have a menorah but the true "light of the world", Jesus, John 8:12
the heavenly sanctuary does not have a golden altar of incense but the true "prayers of the saints", Rev 5:8, 8:3, 4
the heavenly sanctuary does not have golden images and embroidered angels but true cherubim
the heavenly sanctuary does not have the ark of the covenant but the true throne of God on which the Lamb was seated at the right hand of the Father

None of this is to suggest that the heavenly sanctuary is not real; BUT the fact remains that it is never described, so we know nothing about its physical appearance or layout.  Indeed, we are told:

Heb 9:11 - It is an illustration [GR: παραβολὴ parabole] for the
present time, because the gifts and sacrifices being offered were
unable to cleanse the conscience of the worshiper. ... But when Christ
came as high priest of the good things that have come, He went through
the greater and more perfect tabernacle that is not made by hands and
is not a part of this creation.

Thus, the heavenly sanctuary is beyond description because it is not humanly possible to describe it!  Further, we are told that the sanctuary in the desert was exactly according to the pattern shown Moses; but so was Solomon's temple (2 Chron 4:20) which had a lot of different things such as the "molten sea", 10 basins10 gold lampstands,10 tables, etc (2 Chron 4).  So, if the earthly was like the pattern of the heavenly, the question naturally arises, "Which pattern?"
Now to the OP's specific verses:

Ex 25:8, 9 - sanctuary like the pattern seen in the mount

The operative word here is that translated "pattern", viz תַּבְנִית (tabnith) = "pattern" as in Ex 25:9, 40, Deut 4:1617, 18, Josh 22:28, 2 Kings 16:10, 1 Chron 28:11, 12, 18, Ps 106:20, 144:12, Isa 44:13, Eze 8:3, 10, 10:8.  I note several things about this list of occurrences of תַּבְנִית

the word means a representation, not necessarily the actual thing, see especially, 2 Kings 16:10 where it means "sketch"
the earthly sanctuary represented the plan of salvation and not the actual heavenly sanctuary as Hebrews is at pains to point out.

Heb 8:5, 9:24
These two texts make explicit what has just been explained above - the earthly sanctuary was a parable/illustration of the heavenly plan of salvation and NOT a model of the heavenly sanctuary
Behind the Curtain, Heb 6:19
Again, this text simply says that Jesus, as our Great High Priest of the heavenly sanctuary, has entered that heavenly sanctuary as part of His ternal ministration of intercession (1 Tim 2:5) under the New covenant.
